# How to join two data frames, one with a date time index and the other with normal indexing

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, concatenation, datetimeindex

I have a data frame with a date index in the form of YYYY-MM-DD and another data frame with normal indexing, they both have the same number of rows and i want to join the two data frames. Join and merge functions don't work, concat function changes the date format to a date time format by adding hours-mins-sec and there are many null values in the table. So how can i join the two data frames?

this is the code i used:
pd.concat([HK4, adjusted_data], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=False)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePVBP.png)"dataset with date time index"

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGqcr.png)"dataset with normal indexing"
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LBh0.png)"concatenated dataset"

Comment: Could you show some actual data for both dataframes? Show the code you have tried with proper syntax so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JQadrad i updated the question with pictures of the data frames

Answer (score 0):

Try reset index in DataFrame with index YYYY-MM-DD.

```
import pandas as pd
# create first dataframe
d1 = {'dt': ['2020-01-02', '2020-05-05'], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('dt')
# create second dataframe
d2 = {'col3': ['hello', 'world'], 'col4': ['how', 'to']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
# concatenate dataframes
df3 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2], axis=1)
```

[image: merge result]